# Make UIScrollview Paging slower

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In the iOS 6 store, the paging effect of the screen shot is not like the normal behaviour of paging.  How would I slow down the paging effect to simulate something similar?

I already tried using:

```
decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

but that is not working out.

Answer (score 0):

Type of this property is float, so give it some float value. 0.3, 0.5 or something

Comment: Probably I'm paging and is not applied there